# Memory error in python (despite being a small computation)

Tags: python, numpy, graphlab

I am trying to run a code to preform lasso regression using coordinate descent in python using the Graphlab framework.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
l1_penalty = 1.4e8
ro = []
for i in range(0,3):
    ro.append((simple_feature_matrix[:,i]*
              (output - prediction + weights[i]*[simple_feature_matrix[:,i]])).sum()
             )
    print ro
    if i == 0:
        weights[i] = ro[i]
    elif ro[i] < -l1_penalty/2.:
        weights[i] = ro[i] + l1_penalty/2
    elif -l1_penalty/2 <= ro[i] <= l1_penalty/2:
        weights[i] = 0
    elif ro[i] > l1_penalty/2:
        weights[i] = ro[i] - l1_penalty/2
    print weights
    print
```

`output`, `prediction`, `weights`, and `simple_feature_matrix` all are numpy matrices.

I am working on a dataset that has the house sales price of a certain region based on certain features like sqft of living area etc.

`simple_feature_matrix` is numpy matrix of sales with just two of those features. 
 
`output` is a matrix of just the 'price'. 
`prediction` is a matrix with the predicted prices that I computed using a function. 
`weights` is a matrix that has weights for the two features included in `simple_feature_matrix`.

When I run this code once, I get an output, however, running it a second time in the same kernel give me the following error:
[error received on running the code a second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWwQP.jpg)

```
<somepath>/Anaconda2/<somedirectories>/ipykernel/__main__.py:4:Depreciation Warning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Memory Error         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-11-15979f5790d6> in <module>()
      2 ro = []
      3 for i in range(0,3):
--->  4     ro.append((simple_feature_matrix[:,i]*(output - prediction + weights[i]*[simple_feature_matrix[:,i]])).sum())
      5     print ro
      6     if i == 0:

MemoryError:
```

No further explanation is given, it just says there is a memory error. Could anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code that could be copy/pasted so we could run it locally and see the error. At a minimum, can you give the the values of `output.shape, prediction.shape` etc?

Comment: I suspect you're running into unintentional broadcasting. Sometimes when you're arrays are misaligned this can happen. For example if you A and B which are (100, 1) and (1, 100) arrays, `A + B` will create a (100, 100) output. Break up your code into separate lines and see which exact operation is causing the memory error.

Comment: Are the extra pair of brackets around simple_feature_matrix intentional, `[simple_feature_matrix[:,i]]`?

Comment: @BiRico , the pair of brackets is extra, I think I ended up adding them unintentionally. Also, the ro.append(...) statement is producing the memory error.

Comment: @mtrw, both output.shape and prediction.shape give (21613L, ). Also I have not given more code because it all uses a 'sales' dataset that I am computing on.

Comment: I suspect the extra square brackets that @BiRico pointed out are the culprit.  For example, if `x` is a 1D numpy array with length 1000, then `x * (100*[x])` will be a 2D array with shape (100, 1000).  Have you tried running the code again without those brackets?

Comment: @Sabhijiit I can see that `ro.append(...)` is throwing the error :), split that line line up so you can see _which operation_ in that statement is throwing the error.

Comment: @BiRico, @WarrenWeckesser, thanks for the help, it was the extra pair of brackets around `simple_feature_matrix[:,i]` that was causing the problem.